# Place custom post type in add_submenu_page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to place a custom post type under a menu page, I'm Using sandbox theme, 
For example.

- Main Menu
- Sub Menu
- Sub Menu(Custom Post)

This is the sample codes for place a submenu page. But I dont know how to implement it on custom post.

```
 add_submenu_page(
        'sandbox_theme_menu',
        'Projects',
        'Projects',
        'administrator',
        'sandbox_theme_social_examples',
        create_function( null, 'sandbox_theme_display( "social_examples" );' )
    );
```

I'm aware of using menu_position, but it is not what I want to do. 
Any idea on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add show_in_menu when register post type. Example('supports' added to show where place):

```
'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'thumbnail',
    'editor'
    ),
'show_in_menu'=>'options-general.php'
```

Instead of options-general.php place your menu link. You can see it on mouseover. If link has get parameter like options-general.php?page=custom.php copy it all.

Comment: It is displaying, but I created a tab where in it displays all the submenus, I wonder why this custom post type is not displaying on the tabs. :(